# TypeError: Preflight response is not successful

Tags: post, iis, preflight

This is in response to a POST request.
Another error is:  TypeError: Failed to fetch
When the call is made to domain:
`http://mydomainname.com` - it gives this error
`http://mydomainname.ca`  - the call works and the server completes the request.
`http://mydomainname.org` - it gives the error

All three domains point to the same IP address. The POST requests are all the same and originate from JavaScript code.
In the IIS log for the calls that fail, cs-method=OPTIONS and sc-status=405
In the IIS log for the calls that work, cs-method=POST and sc-status=200.

Are there any IIS specialists who can provide some suggestions for fixing this problem?

Comment: How does your web app respond to CORS preflight? If you don't share relevant configuration or code, nobody can help you much.

Comment: You should add the address of your requesting site URL in CORS in your Server/Backend code. Each language or framework might have their own way of adding this, try to search "[backend language] cors" (e.g. "C# cors") in google.

Comment: @Lex Li I don't understand "CORS preflight". I have a rough idea of CORS. Here is the sequence of events:  1. Browser requests the "Contact page" from the website.  2. User fills out the fields on the web page and clicks "Submit". 3. JavaScript formats a JSON object and does a "fetch" with the POST option. The Contact webpage and the servicing REST call are hosted on the same web server. Therefore, why would CORS be involved.?

Comment: @samwu "The requesting site URL". Is not the "requesting site" the browser that initiates the request? If so, then there could be any number of "requesting sites", which cannot be predicted.

Comment: Don't try to guess what's that, but learn from official channels. Microsoft blogged about that https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module Mozilla also has detailed documentation on CORS.

Comment: @Lex Li I read through the Microsoft CORS document. I inserted a <cors > section in my web.config file. The website then returned 500 errors to the caller when the attempt was made to load web pages. When the <cors > section was removed from web.config, the website functionality was restored with the exception of the original bug.  The fact remains that the website correctly handles the POST request when the .ca address is used, and fails when the .com and .org addresses are used.

Comment: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module#additionalDownloads Download the MSI packages and install CORS module on Windows.